# Dell Peripheral Manager 1.5.0 Shows Service Not Running

Tags: webcam

I recently purchased a Dell WB7022 Webcam. After setting it up and installing the Dell Peripheral Manager (version 1.4.2) software everything was fine. I was able to configure the webcam and tweak nerdy settings. Yay! Then I saw there was an update. I performed the update to version 1.5.0 and now when I run the Dell Peripheral Manager software I see a screen saying "Service Not Running. Please restart your PC." After a PC restart nothing changes. I still see the message saying "Service Not Running" and I can't tweak any webcam settings.

Is there a way to manually start the service from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Start the Services applet, find the service, right-click it and select Start.

If it starts correctly, double-click the service and verify that its
"Startup type:" is "Automatic (Delayed Start)".
Finally, reboot to ensure that this is working.

If this does not work for some reason, you might consider returning
to version 1.4.2.

Comment: Or reviewing the error in the event log, and sending Dell the error details.

Comment: I would love to figure out how to reach out to Dell.